# Effective import of CSV into Mysql with PHP to reduce redundancy of data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file approximately 90 MB that I am attempting to parse effectively and insert into a Mysql database using PHP, it contains 45 columns and over 130,000 rows. So, I think just dumping it into the database will not work, or maybe it will.But I decided to build tables with linked foreign keys to reduce the redundancy.

[Here is a link to a diagram of the DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d4hf.jpg)

Now here is where it gets tricky for me. With a schema such as this, how can I take the data from the CSV [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simeoncalixte/bid4all/master/csv/salesdata.csv) and quickly upload it into mysql, while checking for existing duplicate data to update rows and insert new data?
Currently it takes around 4 hours to sort all columns and rows because I am doing it one row at a time. Basically how can I make this faster?

A link to my code is [here](https://github.com/simeoncalixte/bid4all/blob/master/php/dbscripts/salesListInsert%20-%20Copy.php).

Comment: Import CSV file to master  table  Using LOAD DATA INFILE and then  workout on saving to other mapping tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via command line if you have access .. Let's say your `csv` is `delimited` by pipes `|`   Then you would:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" --local-infile scrapping -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yourfile.csv'  INTO TABLE database_name.table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Something in that range of 130,000 rows should only take a couple minutes if that ..

Comment: what about foreign keys? because I separate the data in mysql based on location, sale date, color, damages etc

Comment: See my edited answer ...  It disables foreign key checks for that single session only ..

Comment: Also this is assuming your foreign keys in your data are good.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the foreign keys, unique keys and autocommit as per [this article](https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts).

I ran into this problem just recently and it sped up my conversion tremendously. Here's a snippet from my conversion (you'll have to adapt it):

```
$tablesAffected = ['sch_booking_interpreters','sch_booking_clinicians','sch_bookings'];

$bufDb->exec("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
$bufDb->exec("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0");
$bufDb->exec("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");

foreach($tablesAffected as $tbl) {
    // https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts#disable-mysql-jmp
    $bufDb->exec("alter table ?? disable keys", [$tbl]);
}


foreach($thing as $thang) {
    $bufDb->insert('thing',$thang);
}

foreach($tablesAffected as $tbl) {
    $bufDb->exec("alter table ?? enable keys", [$tbl]);
}

$bufDb->exec("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1");
$bufDb->exec("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1");
$bufDb->exec("COMMIT");

echo \Console::FG_GREEN . "∎\n" . \Console::RESET;
```

You will of course have to make sure your data is "good" (no FK violations).